# Exception in thread on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, tweepy

**Backrground** 
 
I have deployed an app on Heroku but I'm getting the below error. On my local server it was running fine. Basically I'm using Flask and Tweepy to send a few tweets back whenever I send a request, which is sent in every few seconds and then gets disconnected after a minute

```
class LiveStream(Resource):
    """ Starts the Stream """
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('search_text', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('disconnect_time', type=float, required=True)

    def post(self):
        search_text = LiveStream.parser.parse_args()['search_text']
        myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=MyStreamListener())
        myStream.filter(track=[search_text], async=True)

        stream_start_time = time.time()
        disconnect_time = LiveStream.parser.parse_args()['disconnect_time']
        t = threading.Thread(target=stream_disconnect, name='stream_disconnect', args=(stream_start_time, disconnect_time))
        t.start()
        connected = True
        return {'message': 'Stream has started'}

def stream_disconnect(start_time, last_for):
    while True:
        if (time.time() - start_time) >= last_for:
            global stream_list, connected, myStream
            myStream.disconnect()
            myStream = None 
            stream_list = []
            connected = False
            break
    print('Stream disconnected')
    return
```

This is the error I'm getting on Heroku Logs. I dont think that Tweepy has been causing this and Twitter has been disconnecting me since It still runs fine on my local server. I suppose its something that I have done wrong. By the way, `MyStreamListener` appends tweet to `stream_list` which is being returned to me.
 
**My error**

```
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185114+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread
> Thread-4:      2017-12-29T12:51:49.185134+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 601, in urlopen           2017-12-29T12:51:49.185132+00:00
> app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185135+00:00 app[web.1]:     chunked=chunked)     
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185135+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 346, in _make_request     2017-12-29T12:51:49.185136+00:00
> app[web.1]:     self._validate_conn(conn)     
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185137+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 850, in _validate_conn    2017-12-29T12:51:49.185137+00:00
> app[web.1]:     conn.connect()                
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185139+00:00 app[web.1]:     ssl_context=context) 
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185138+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 326, in connect               2017-12-29T12:51:49.185140+00:00
> app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py",
> line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket        2017-12-29T12:51:49.185141+00:00
> app[web.1]:     return context.wrap_socket(sock,
> server_hostname=server_hostname)                                      
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185141+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket  
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185142+00:00 app[web.1]:     _context=self,
> _session=session)                                                                               2017-12-29T12:51:49.185143+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__     
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185144+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.do_handshake()  
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185144+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185145+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()    2017-12-29T12:51:49.185146+00:00
> app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line
> 689, in do_handshake                                      
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185146+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()    2017-12-29T12:51:49.185147+00:00
> app[web.1]: ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
> (_ssl.c:777)                                               
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185148+00:00 app[web.1]:                          
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185149+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the
> above exception, another exception occurred:                          
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185150+00:00 app[web.1]:                          
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185150+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last): 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185151+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 440, in send                   2017-12-29T12:51:49.185152+00:00
> app[web.1]:     timeout=timeout               
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185153+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 639, in urlopen           2017-12-29T12:51:49.185153+00:00
> app[web.1]:     _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185154+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py",
> line 388, in increment             2017-12-29T12:51:49.185155+00:00
> app[web.1]:     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or
> ResponseError(cause))                                                
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185156+00:00 app[web.1]:
> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length (Caused
> by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol
> (_ssl.c:777)'),))                  2017-12-29T12:51:49.185156+00:00
> app[web.1]:                                   
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185157+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the
> above exception, another exception occurred:                          
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185158+00:00 app[web.1]:                          
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185159+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last): 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185160+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in
> _bootstrap_inner                             2017-12-29T12:51:49.185161+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.run()           
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185162+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run    
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185162+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)                             
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185163+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py",
> line 294, in _run                    2017-12-29T12:51:49.185163+00:00
> app[web.1]:     raise exception               
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185165+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py",
> line 247, in _run                    2017-12-29T12:51:49.185165+00:00
> app[web.1]:     verify=self.verify)           
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185166+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 508, in request                2017-12-29T12:51:49.185167+00:00
> app[web.1]:     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)                 
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185167+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 618, in send                   2017-12-29T12:51:49.185168+00:00
> app[web.1]:     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)                   
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185169+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 506, in send                   2017-12-29T12:51:49.185170+00:00
> app[web.1]:     raise SSLError(e, request=request)                    
> 2017-12-29T12:51:49.185174+00:00 app[web.1]:
> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length (Caused
> by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol
> (_ssl.c:777)'),))
```